# How to type Japanese in Windows 10 command line?

Tags: command-line, ime

I've tried both the MS IME and the Google IME, but both auto-disabled itself when I'm typing in the command lines, thus I'm only getting English letters. Already tried "cmd /u" and "chcp 65001", and neither helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Hi I fond this solution in the Windows forums, maybe it's help you

How about if you set the location as “Japan”?

Meanwhile, please change language for non-Unicode to "Japanese" as following steps:

1. open the Control Panel;
2. click Region and Language;
3. on the Administrative tab, under Language for non-Unicode programs, click "change system locale...";
4. set the Current system locale as "Japanese(Japan)".

Best regards,

Comment: sorrily not working.